# Error FFMpeg Laravel Filters on HLS conversion

Tags: php, linux, laravel, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to transform a mp4 to m3u8 video format using ffmpeg library on Laravel.

Currently it works with the bitrates and the size of the generated videos, but when I try to add the filters to define the resolutions, it generates the following log error.

> 20-11-03 16:55:19] local.ERROR: custom_filter filter is supported
> starting from 0.3 ffmpeg version; your ffmpeg version is
> git-2020-08-26-8f2c1f2 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
> (FFMpeg\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): custom_filter filter is
> supported starting from 0.3 ffmpeg version; your ffmpeg version is
> git-2020-08-26-8f2c1f2 at
> C:\laragon\www\maquillate\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\Media\AdvancedMedia.php:344)

This is my current implementation

```
    $lowBitrate = (new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libfaac', 'libx264'))->setKiloBitrate(250);
    $midBitrate = (new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libfaac', 'libx264'))->setKiloBitrate(500);
    $highBitrate = (new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libfaac', 'libx264'))->setKiloBitrate(1000);


        FFMpeg::FromDisk('local')->open($media)
            ->exportForHLS()
            ->setSegmentLength(10) // optional
            ->setKeyFrameInterval(48) // optional
            ->addFormat($lowBitrate, function ($video) {
                $video->addLegacyFilter(function ($filters) {
                    $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 480));
                });
            })
            ->addFormat($midBitrate)
            ->addFormat($highBitrate)
            ->save('public/hls/' . $video->id . '/video.m3u8');
```

If I remove the filters from this code, they work without any problem, but I need to add these dimensions.

this is the documentation of Laravel FFmpeg what I need to do:  https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg#hls

**Note: my operating system is Windows 10**

Comment: You should probably follow this issue: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/756

Comment: I tested my implementation on a linux server and it is working without any problem, it is an issue with windows.

Comment: @TwistCode Did you get any video blur issue? because I am having blur issue?

Comment: @ManeeshRao No, It had no blur.

Comment: @TwistCode Can you see my code. It is giving me blur vide after conversion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515850/converted-video-is-getting-blur-in-ffmpeg

Comment: Hi! you could remove the filters method.

Comment: @TwistCode, I removed the filters but it is not converting now.

Comment: @TwistCode I removed filter, resize and synchronize. it is working but it is taking more than 2 mins to convert the 2MB video file.

Comment: Are you running it in your local? What hardware do you have @ManeeshRao

Comment: I have 4GB ram. it is on server.