# Converted video is getting blur in FFMpeg

Tags: php, laravel-5, video, ffmpeg

I have a video and converted to mp4 format. I am using FFMpeg to convert the video. Video conversion is successfully done but video is getting blur. any Help?

> ```
>     $fileName = "convertedVideoFile.mp4";
>     $mp4File = "oldVideoFile.mp4";
>     
>     $format = new X264('aac', 'libx264');
>
>     // create object
>     $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
>         'ffmpeg.binaries'  => exec('which ffmpeg'),
>         'ffprobe.binaries' => exec('which ffprobe'),
>         'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
>         'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
>     ]);
>
>     // open the file.
>     $video = $ffmpeg->open($mp4File);
>     $video
>         ->filters()
>         ->resize(new Dimension(320, 240))
>         ->synchronize();
>
>     $video->save($format, 'video/'.$fileName)
> ```

Comment: What do you mean with blur? Compression artifacts?

Comment: @Felixkruemel Video is become unclear or less distinct after conversion.

Comment: Please upload a short example before/after. Two screenshots are also enough